# Where can I find documentation about generating CMS pages as demo data in Shopware 6?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I am trying to implement custom demo data that is generated once the plugin is activated (similar to the Shopware plugin *SwagPlatformDemoData*). Part of this demo data are generated CMS pages, although I cannot find any documentation online outlining different methods of generating these pages. The only reference I could find was the 'startseite' cms page generated within the *SwagPlatformDemoData* plugin (which generates a image on a full-width section, whereas I need to generate text in a main section and a sidebar)

Where would I find documentation for this so that I can implement this further?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the [`DemodataCommand`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/562d44b6a80f968fbb6d789629da1da30f314117/src/Core/Framework/Demodata/Command/DemodataCommand.php). It utilizes the `DemodataService` which uses entity specific generators, implementations of `DemodataGeneratorInterface`, e.g. the [`CustomerGenerator`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/992c811bfba458fb429d7db69d0ae98001c29436/src/Core/Framework/Demodata/Generator/CustomerGenerator.php). You can register your own generator by tagging it accordingly:

```xml
<service id="MyPlugin\Core\Framework\Demodata\Generator\CmsPageGenerator">
    <!-- all the services you need -->

    <tag name="shopware.demodata_generator" option-name="cms-pages" option-default="60"/>
</service>
```

Then you should be able to just replicate what the `DemotdataCommand` does, calling the `DemodataService` to create data using your own generator.

Regarding the creation of fleshed out CMS pages with random content you may want to look at the [`CreatePageCommand`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/b9710d639753cf42718987ab83467ac52a1170dd/src/Core/Content/Cms/Command/CreatePageCommand.php) which creates pages that are to some degree randomized.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a lifecycle and define what need to be installed/removed when (de)activating the plugin. Documentation can be found here: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/plugin-lifecycle#overview

After you've created the lifecycle, you need to create a function and add your content to `$this->cmsPageRepository->create($cmsPage, $context);`

You can use the structure explained in this documentation: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/concepts/commerce/core/shopping-experiences-cms#structure